# run python module by just typing folder name

Tags: python

I have `__init__.py` in a folder called `test_module`. in the `__init__.py`  i have below code. however when i try to execute from parent folder of `test_module` with following command `python test_module` i get following error `can't find '__main__' module in 'test_module`. is this not possible? or will i have to run `python test_module/__init__.py`?

```
def main():
    print('test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try with [`python -m test_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? It does not seem to be very pythonic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__init__.py` module is executed when the package is imported. The purpose of `__init__.py` files per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) is as follows:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

In order for a Python package to be directly executed, it needs to have an **entry point**, designated by a module  within the package named `__main__.py`. Thus the error `can't find '__main__' module in 'test_module'`: You have attempted to directly execute the package, but Python cannot locate an entry point to begin executing top-level code.

---

Consider the following package structure:

```
test_module/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
```

Where `__init__.py` contains the following:

```
print("Running: __init__.py")
```

Where `__main__.py` contains the following:

```
print("Running: __main__.py")
```

When we execute the `test_module` package with the command `python test_module`, we get the following output:

```
> python test_module
Running: __main__.py
```

However, if we enter the Python shell and `import test_module`, the output is as follows:

```
>>> import test_module
Running: __init__.py
```

---

Thus in order to get the behavior you want when attempting to directly execute `test_module`, simply create a new `__main__.py` file within `test_module` and transfer the code from `__init__.py` to the new `__main__.py`.